# How to get a boolean out of python minidom

Tags: python, xml, minidom

This made me sad:

```
me@here ~
$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 20 2014, 09:44:42)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> b=False
>>> b
False
>>> str(b)
'False'
>>> s=str(b)
>>> s
'False'
>>> b=bool(s)
>>> b
True
>>>
```

So, how do I get a boolean value from a xml document using the minidom? getAttribute gives me a string and I could always do:

```
attr = el.getAttribute( 'bodacious' )
if attr in [ '1', 'true', 'True', 'TRUE', 'y', 'Y', 'yes', 'Yes', 'YES' ]:
    return True # a bodacious element
else:
    return False # a most non-bodacious element
```

but it seems quite arbitrary. Is there a better way?

Comment: Non-empty sequences (including strings) evaluate truthy in Python - this is often helpful! Aside from using a single case (e.g. `attr.lower() in ...`) and sanitising your input (why are there so many possible "booleans"?) there's not much neater you can get.

Comment: `bool(str)` doesn't convert boolean string names to type `bool`. Instead, it does the same as `if str:`, so this is important to be consistent. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool

Comment: You can add your own method to check the string is actually a boolean. But there is no other way as far as I know.

Comment: There are so many boolean values because the many engineers who have to edit this file will spend the next five years attempting to get the parser to recognise their own personal opinion of what 'bool' ought to be in xml and failing and then they will whine at whoever is the current script-bitch until it gets added as yet another option. It ain't pretty but it is what bitter experience leads me to expect.

Answer (score 1):

If those are all the things that can be true in your minidom, then yes. You can be a little more concise, though:

```
attr = el.getAttribute( 'bodacious' ).lower()
return attr in ( '1', 'true', 'y', 'yes' )
```

or even inline it:

```
return el.getAttribute( 'bodacious' ).lower() in ( '1', 'true', 'y', 'yes' )
```

though if you do it often you'll want to extract the list of true values, something like:

```
TRUE_VALS = ( '1', 'true', 'True', 'y', 'yes', 'Y', 'Yes', 'YES' )
```

and then:

```
return el.getAttribute( 'bodacious' ) in TRUE_VALS:
```

Answer (score 1):

**On the one hand**: How python gets boolean values out of objects

Each python object has an intrinsic boolean value. In general, every object is truthy (i.e. it returns `True` when passed to `bool`) unless it is `''`, `None`, `0`, `False` or an empty container (like `[]` or `{}`). (You can customize this behaviour in your own classes)

This means, that any non empty string has a truthy value, leading to possibly confusing results to people used to other languages with implicit type coercion like PHP or JS. But it is consistent, and this is what you want while programming:

```
>>> bool('False')
True
>>> bool('Very false')
True
>>> bool('')
False
>>> bool('0')
True
```

**On the other hand**: XML as data transfer language sucks.

You need to keep track of truthy or falsy values. Asuming you want to define truth values, and the rest are falsy, you can do the following:

```
# Define this in load-time code instead of runtime to avoid redefining it on each call.
truthy_values = {'true', '1', ...}
...
# Then, in some function, check the value in this way:
return attr.lower() in truthy_values
```

This minimizes the special cases you have to handle. It entails many risks as well, for instance `'0'` will return `True`

Anyway, my real hint is to abandon XML once and for all. Your life will be better and more satisfactory if you use JSON or YAML.

Comment: Oh yes, I have been fighting a YAML Jihad at work for the past two years, but this particular file must remain as XML for the moment! I was just curious on what people thought a 'natural' way of getting a boolean from attributes ought to be.

(sorry for the incorrect edit - I hope it was obvious that that was incompetence and not trolling)

Comment: @PatB yeah no worries, it was obvious :)

If you still have to work with XML, I would make sure that only two possible string values come into that field, let's say `True` and `False`, and then use a dictionary `{'True': True, 'False': False}` to fetch the value you are looking for. And if it does not fit, let it crash...